# Why is my Matrix returning a Stack overflow?

Tags: c#

I'm very new to C# and am still learning all it's little quirks. I'm attempting to set up a camera which moves position based on a Left click and the mouse position, but am getting a Stack overflow with my current code, It looks like it should work from what I have read and seen but I just can't seem to locate the problem,

any help would be appreciated.
Here is my Camera class

```
class Camera
{
    Vector2 viewPosition = Vector2.Zero;

    public Matrix viewMatrix
    {
        get { return viewMatrix; }
        set { return; }
    }

    public void Update(InputHandler inputHandler)
    {
        Vector2 mousePosition = inputHandler.MousePosition;
        bool LeftClick = inputHandler.LeftButton;

        if (LeftClick == true)
        {
            viewPosition = mousePosition;
        }

        viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation(viewPosition.X,viewPosition.Y, 0);


    }
}
```

and my Draw method for the only objects currently being drawn.

```
        public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Texture2D sprite, Camera camera)
    {
        spriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred,BlendState.AlphaBlend,null,null,null,null,camera.viewMatrix);
        spriteBatch.Draw(sprite, spritePosition, null, Color.White,angle,origin,1.0f,SpriteEffects.None,0);
        spriteBatch.End();

    }
```

Comment: don't know the reason, but btw, please don't do `if (LeftClick == true)`, simply `if (LeftClick)` is enough with `bool`. You may use a debugger and step through the code to see what's happening. `StackOverflowException` is mostly caused by (unintented) infinite recursion which floods the stack with return addresses.

Comment: Look at your `viewMatrix` getter - that's just calling itself.

Comment: And the setter doesn’t do anything, so `viewMatrix = Matrix.CreateTranslation` will not work either.

Comment: Basically, you need to learn more about what properties do.

Comment: Change your viewMatrix code to: public Matrix ViewMatrix {get; set;}

Answer (score 2):

Check your viewMatrix property. The accessor is referencing itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [auto-implemented property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx) accessors.

```
    public Matrix ViewMatrix {get; set;}
```